# PHPUnit 9.x + PHP7.3.21 syntax question, regards errors

Tags: php, phpunit, php-7.2

I have a need to use the latest version of PHPUnit however I am seeing this in the framework:

`public function dataName(): int|string { return $this->dataName; }`

And I am getting an error in response to this, and other LOC in the TestCase.php file. Why is this? There are other errors as well, such as from these lines:

`private array $backupGlobalsExcludeList = []; private ?bool $backupStaticProperties = null;`
private array $backupStaticPropertiesExcludeList = [];`

Why is there a ?bool when I've never seen this before in PHP? More to the point, what do I need to do to remove the errors?

Comment: From https://phpunit.de/announcements/phpunit-9.html - PHPUnit now requires PHP 7.3 (or newer) (as you tag your question 7.2)

Comment: Thanks Nigel; that's a pain I need to upgrade WAMP now :(

Comment: `public function dataName(): int|string` is from the unreleased PHPUnit 10 which requires PHP 8.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for clearing that up and yes, I am seeing those errors on PHP7.4.x. I guess I should use PHPUnit 8.x then...